# Creating a regex to parse a build version

Tags: regex, sed

I'm tyring to grab a build verson from a file that contains the following line:

```
 <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("004.005.0862")>
```

and I would like it to return

```
4.5.862
```

I'm using sed in dos and got the following to spit out 004.005.0862

```
echo "<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("004.005.0862")>" | sed "s/[^0-9,.]//g"
```

How do I get rid of the leading zeros for each part of the build number?

Comment: Your `echo` should have outer single quotes instead of double quotes so that the inner quotes are part of the quoted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex to do this in a single step looks like this:

```
^.*"0*([0-9]+\.)0*([0-9]+\.)0*([0-9]+).*
```

with sed-specific escaping and as a full expression, it becomes a little longer:

```
s/^.*"0*\([0-9]\+\.\)0*\([0-9]\+\.\)0*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1\2\3/g
```

---

The regex breaks down as

```
    ^             # start-of-string
    .*"           # anything, up to a double quote
    0*([0-9]+\.)  # any number of zeros, then group 1: at least 1 digit and a dot
    0*([0-9]+\.)  # any number of zeros, then group 2: at least 1 digit and a dot
    0*([0-9]+)    # any number of zeros, then group 3: at least 1 digit
    .*            # anything up to the end of the string
```

Comment: Very nice!  What does the \1\2\3 at the end of the sed expression do?

Comment: @fasttimes: They output the capture groups (what matches between the `\(` and `\)`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `... | sed "s/[^0-9]*0*([1-9][0-9,.]*)/\1/g"`. I'm using a subpattern to filter out the part you need, ignoring leading zeros and non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many more clever ways, but one that works (and is reasonably easy to understand) is to pipe it through additional calls:

```
echo "version(004.005.0862)" | sed "s/[^0-9,.]//g" | sed "s/^0*//g" | sed "s/\.0*/./g"
```

Comment: Just because I'm curious I'd like to see the clever version, but your way works great!

Comment: Arguments can be made either way, but for things like this, I rather like the simpler (even though possibly less technically elegant) solutions. It may be nicer for when the next person comes along and has to figure out what it means.